Objectness/IoU loss computation in YOLOX model
I've coded YOLOX from sctrach, but I have a problem with the objectness loss (IoU branch). In the paper they not report how the loss is computed. However, searching online I found this formula
YOLOX total loss
The problem is that, if for regression and class loss just positives prediction are used, for the objectness, all the predictions, including the negatives, should be used. So dividing by just the number of positives should not be correct in this case, and will lead to huge objectness loss values ?
Additionally, in the official code at this link https://github.com/Megvii-BaseDetection/YOLOX/blob/main/yolox/models/yolo_head.py, the model seems to solve the objectness using as a target the conversion of the foreground mask, a torch tensor of boolean values named fg_mask, to float.
This would mean that the loss does not learn the IoU, but tries to predict ones for positives and zeros for negatives.
What I'm doing wrong ? Can someone help me to figure out how to compute the objectness/IoU value and if it has a weight factor for scaling before summing such a value in the final loss ?
I tried first solving prediction the IoU just for the positives, but I'm not convinced about that because this way the network is just learning to predict "good values" for just the positives and "don't care" for all the other grid cells.
Then I tried using the predicted values with the target vector composed one ones and zeros (one for positives, zero for negatives), but still dividing for the number of positives.
Then I tried creating the target vector using for the positives the IoU value with respect to the assigned GT, for the negatives the highest IoU that cell has with all the GTs in the image and after computing the loss still dividing by the number of positives.
Finally I tried the same configuration as the previous case but dividing by the total number of grid cells, in my case (13x13)+(26x26)+(52x52).
For all the configurations, I passed the objectness value after passing it to the sigmoid to the BCE loss, which should be more or less equivalent to pass it directly (without sigmoid) to the BCEWithLogitLoss (maybe the latter is more stable for the gradient computation).
None of the configurations lead to good results. What I'm doing wrong ?
